# How do you install Angular on windows 7

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows, buildbot

Hi this should be pretty straight forward but I'm getting stuck. I installed buildbot (0.9.06b)on my machine a Windows 7 machine. I have managed to get it up and running however when I try to display the web page(IE8), I get the error Angular not defined. This being a brand new windows box I was not too surprised. I proceeded to download NodeJS the executable and run it on the machine so Node is installed. I then went to [Angular website](https://angularjs.org/) downloaded the zip file, but i'm not sure what to do next?
I tried

> npm install Angular

and a few variations i.e specifying the version, unzipping the file. But still cannot install it.
My machine is behind a firewall so it cannot just go off to the web and get more stuff. It all has to work locally.
How should I go about installing Angular?
How can I check that Angular is installed?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Checkout [this github repo](https://github.com/pbaio/node-angular-example) for an example working app using Node, Angular, Express and Bower.

---

The you're reason receiving the Angular not defined message is because you're not serving Angular from your web server to the client.

Installing Angular from `npm` typically means that you're going to serve it from your `node_modules` folder or you will be using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/). I would advise against using `npm install --save angular`, your `node_modules` should contain just server-side dependencies if you're not using Browserify in most cases. Additionally, NPM packages use CommonJS, which [isn't preferred in the browser](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html). Browserify is a popular solution for writing CommonJS style code that can be bundled into a browser compatible js file. They have [docs](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) to get up and running with.

Alternatively you can install Angular from [Bower.io](http://bower.io/). Bower is a package manager for client-side packages. Bower has a [huge package library](http://bower.io/search/), including many of the packages that are also available through NPM.

Its also worth mentioning that unless you're doing a `npm install -g` for global installs, you should add the `--save` flag when doing an `npm install` or an `npm uninstall` for your project dependencies. `--save` adds any packages you've installed to your `package.json` file as dependency.

#### Here is an example of how to serve Angular from Node.js

This example just uses Node.js, Express, EJS (for Express View Engine Rendering), Bower & Angular

```
npm install -g bower
cd <your project directory>  

// answer questions about your project
// this will create your package.json file
npm init 
npm install --save express
npm install --save ejs

// answer the questions about your project
// this will create your bower.json file
bower init 
bower install --save angular
```

**Directory Structure**

```
- Project Folder
  - node_modules
  - bower_components
  - public
    - app
      - app.js
  - views
    - index.html
  - bower.json
  - package.json
  - server.js
```

**The Angular App - public/app/app.js**

```
// This is a super simple Hello World AngularJS App
(function() {
  angular
    .module('yourApp', [])
    .controller('YourController', ['$scope', function($scope) {         
      $scope.hello = 'Hello World';
    }]);
})();
```

Angular must be loaded just like any other Client-Side library, so it will need to be included in your pages within the `<head>` tag.

**The View - views/index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- load Angular into our HTML Page -->
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- load our Angular App in -->
    <script src="/public/app/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="yourApp">
    <div ng-controller="YourController">
      {{ hello }}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In order for this to work you will need to actually have a web server running that will serve the files you're looking for when you call them. You can do this using [Express](http://expressjs.com).

**The Node.js Web Server - server.js**

```
var express = require('express);
var path = require('path');
var app = express();


// Setup View Engines
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// Serve files from your "public" directory
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public)));

// Serve files from your "bower_components" directory
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/bower_components')));

// GET index.html route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  return res.render('index');
});

// Start our server and start to listen
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
  console.log('listening');
});
```

Now all you need to do is `node server.js` and visit your site at `localhost` or wherever you've specified and you should be up and running.

Comment: you forgot a closing `'` in `express` and `public`; `var express = require('express);` and `
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public)));`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install angular using these steps-

1> Angular requires Node.js version 8.x or 10.x.,Check node.js version by-

```
node -v
```

2>Install node.js,go to [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org).

3>Install npm-

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

4>Create a project-

```
ng new my-app
```

> here my-app is project name

5> Would you like to add Angular routing? No

6> Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS

7> Go to the workspace folder

```
cd my-app
```

8> Launch the server by using the CLI command ng serve, with the --open option.

```
ng serve --open
```

9> opens your browser to http://localhost:4200/.